# pdb: skip restart when finished

Tags: python, pdb

With

```
python -m pdb -c "c" script.py
```

the debug mode is entered, when a problem occurs. From the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html#module-pdb), I figured out that the option `-c "c"` (Python 3.2+) saves me to hit <kbd>c</kbd>  + <kbd>Enter</kbd> each time at program start.

Yet, when the program finishes normally, it outputs
`The program finished and will be restarted` and
I still have to hit <kbd>q</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> to the quit the program.
Is there a way to skip this as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add multiple commands for `-c` in a sequence.

**METHOD 1: Quitting only if no error is encountered**

You can just give another command `q` to jump out of pdb mode incase no error is encountered. If an error is encountered, however, it will enter the debug mode where you will have to continue hitting `c` and enter to move forward.

```
python -mpdb -c "c" -c "q" script.py
```

*Not encountering an error (quit immediately!)-*

```
(base) $ python -mpdb -c "c" -c "q" script.py
The program finished and will be restarted
(base) $
```

*Encountering an error (enter debug mode!)-*

```
(base) $ python -mpdb -c "c" -c "q" script.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/pdb.py", line 1701, in main
    pdb._runscript(mainpyfile)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/pdb.py", line 1570, in _runscript
    self.run(statement)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/bdb.py", line 585, in run
    exec(cmd, globals, locals)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Projects/Random/script.py", line 6, in <module>
    """
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'thispackagedoesntexist'
Uncaught exception. Entering post mortem debugging
Running 'cont' or 'step' will restart the program
Post mortem debugger finished. The script.py will be restarted
> /Projects/Random/script.py(6)<module>()
-> """
(Pdb)
```

---

**METHOD 2: Quitting irrespective of error or not**

You can use `echo "q"` and pass it to the next (`pdb`) command by using the `|` in the following way. This will run the second command once and immediately take the output of `echo "q"` to quit -

```
echo "q" | python -mpdb -c "c" script.py
```

This hits q after the program is done running the script in debug mode. Debug automatically quits after encountering (or not encountering) an error.

*Not encountering an error (quit immediately!)-*

```
(base) $ echo "q" | python -mpdb -c "c" script.py
The program finished and will be restarted
> /Projects/Random/script.py(6)<module>()
-> """
(Pdb) (base) $
```

*Encountering an error (quit immediately!)-*

```
(base) $ echo "q" | python -mpdb -c "c" script.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/pdb.py", line 1701, in main
    pdb._runscript(mainpyfile)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/pdb.py", line 1570, in _runscript
    self.run(statement)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/bdb.py", line 585, in run
    exec(cmd, globals, locals)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File /Projects/Random/script.py", line 6, in <module>
    """
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'thispackagedoesntexist'
Uncaught exception. Entering post mortem debugging
Running 'cont' or 'step' will restart the program
> /Projects/Random/script.py(6)<module>()
-> """
(Pdb) Post mortem debugger finished. The script.py will be restarted
> /Projects/Random/script.py(6)<module>()
-> """
(Pdb) 
(base) $
```

---

Here is the list of commands you can use with pdb -

```
(Pdb) help

Documented commands (type help <topic>):
========================================
EOF    c          d        h         list      q        rv       undisplay
a      cl         debug    help      ll        quit     s        unt
alias  clear      disable  ignore    longlist  r        source   until
args   commands   display  interact  n         restart  step     up
b      condition  down     j         next      return   tbreak   w
break  cont       enable   jump      p         retval   u        whatis
bt     continue   exit     l         pp        run      unalias  where
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use --
`python3 -mpdb -c "q" -c "c" example.py`

[Link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html#pdbcommand-quit)